# Rails and Devise - Creating an initial user - missing encrypted password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm a little confused with how Devise is supposed to work with your initial admin user.

I can put a line like this in my seed file

```
User.create! :name => 'admin', :email => 'admin@examples.com', :password => 'p@ssw0rd!', :password_confirmation => 'p@ssw0rd!'
```

But when I check my sqlite database I notice it generates no encrypted_password.
What am I doing wrong? Do I need to call another method? Not sure what Devise handles here automatically for you.

**UPDATE:**

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails', '3.0.10'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'cloudfiles'
gem 'devise'
gem 'fog'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~>2.1.0'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

**UPDATE 2**
My devise settings of my User class

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Comment: i noticed that too when i was using faker gem

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you using other gems that might be messing with devise?

Comment: How do my settings compare to yours?

Answer (score 1):

Please

- post the your logfile section for this issue
- post your config/initializers/devise.rb (settings only, without comments)

Hopefully this helps to get it!

And, ehm, did you run the generator (rails generate devise:install)?

Comment: The problem was caused by bringing in an existing model. I still had attr_accessor for password and confirmation. Once I removed these it started working correctly. Please add 'see comments' to your answer. And +1 I should have included more of the config details.

Comment: I had the same problem and your comment show me the way, THANKS A LOT ! ... so removing attr_accessor for password was the key !

Comment: removing `attr_accessor` for password worked for me.